# python grpc: setting timeout per grpc call

Tags: grpc-python

Is there a way to specify timeout per grpc call with python.
I am experiencing more than 1 minute delay in receiving response.
I want the api to return some error in case it is taking longer that specified time. I am using blocking grpc call.

Answer (score 2):

You can look up the information you want at gRPC Python's [API reference](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.__call__). Setting timeout should be as simple as:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(...)
stub = ...(channel)
stub.AnRPC(request, timeout=5)  # 5 seconds timeout
```